# LinQ - Retrieve column names and values

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures

I've created a method that call a stored procedure that retrieves a lot of columns. I'm trying to get each column name/value and put in Dictionary.

I was doing it using a `SqlDataReader` and it was very easy:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sqlDataReader.FieldCount; i++)
{
    user.Attributes.Add(sqlDataReader.GetName(i),
    sqlDataReader.GetValue(i));
}
```

Now I need to change it to use Linq, call my stored procedure and return the object `User.Attributes` filled with results from database.

I'm stuck in how to create a method that retrieves those values using Linq and how to create partial class (can I do it using a dictionary?).

Here is what I've done:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name = "dbo.myProc")]
public Dictionary<string, object> LoadUsersList(int campId, int selectionId, string threadGUID)
{
    // How to turn it in a Dictionary containing Key ( Column Name ) - 
    //Value ( Column Value )? Can i do without use partial class?
    this.ExecuteQuery<System.Collections.IEnumerable>
             (String.Format("EXEC dbo.myProc @BusinessId = {0}, @UserId = {1}",
                 businessId, userId)); 
    return null;
}
```

Any help?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to map the stored procedure?

Comment: Yes but i need to get columns names dynamically.